# SQL subqueries - depending on the values of the first query

Tags: php

I am a beginner and am creating a web page using dreamweaver. I need a SQL query that will allow a second drop box to drop down values based on the result of the fist dropbox.

I have a MySQL table as Cars() and the other table car model and the third which is the car year.

This is what i have done so far:

1. select distinct car from cars - this brings out the values in the first dropbox
2. select distinct carmodel from carmodel where (carmodelid = carid) 
   now this is where I have the problem, binging out the values in the second dropdown depending on the values of the first dropdown using a SQL query.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT carmodel FROM carmodel WHERE carmodelid IN (SELECT carid FROM cars)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will help Patrick. He obviously needs auto-populated linked dropdown boxes but his question is wrong with respect to his meaning.

Comment: @Cogicero: I agree with you on the point if OP wants the result set to be driven by the selected value of first drop down or whether OP wants all the models. The question was little vauge

Comment: True, it's really confusing how the Op states the question. Either of us could be right but I assumed because of this part of the OP (emphasis mine) "the values in the second drodown DEPENDING on the values of the first dropdown using a SQL QUERY". But I guessed OP doesn't really know SQL cannot achieve the intended aim.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with plain PHP because by the time the user is selecting the first dropdown, PHP has completed its work on the server-side. You will need javascript and I always recommend jQuery.

For the MySQL queries I am using a PHP PDO class that I created for myself and I am used to (don't bother about that) but in essence, just fetch the PHP queries how you know best, andmaking sure you are not left open to SQL injections. You will need to google and read up on AJAX and PHP using jQuery. This is fast, dirty and untested so if you have questions, hit me up in the comments. Here goes:

```
   <label><span>Choose a Car:</span>
        <select name="car" id="car" class="validate[required] longtext" onchange="getCarModels();">
            <option value="">-------Make a Selection------</option>
            <?php
            try{
                $carCount = DB::getDB("mysql", 1, array("carID"))->query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(%s%)) FROM cars")->fetchColumn();
                if ($carCount > 0){
                    $car_sql="SELECT DISTINCT %s% FROM cars";
                    foreach (DB::getDB("mysql", 1, array("carID", "carName"))->query($car_sql) as $row){                                        
                        echo '<option value="'.$row[carID].'">'.$row[carName].'</option>';
                    }
                }
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                print "SQL Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
                exit();
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label id="carModelsBox" style="display:none;">
        <span>Select Model:</span>
            <select name="carmodel" id="carmodel" class="validate[required] longtext">
        </select>
    </label>
```

And javascript

```
function getCarModels(){
    var carID = $('#car option:selected').val();
    if (carID == "") {
        $('#carModelsBox').slideUp("fast");
    }
    $.getJSON("ajax.carmodels.php", {carID:carID}, function(data){
        if (data.success){
            $('#carmodel').html(data.models);
        }else{
            $('#carModelsBox').append("<p>There are no models</p>");
        }
        $('#car').blur();
        $('#carModelsBox').slideDown("fast"); $('#carmodel').focus();
    });
}
```

This javascript file will call a PHP file via AJAX. This file is ajax.carmodels.php and it will receive the carID via GET. Snippet of the code below:

```
if ($carID!=''){
    try {
        $carModelCount = DB::getDB("mysql", 1, array("carmodel.id"))->query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(%s%)) FROM cars, carmodel WHERE carmodel.id = cars.id")->fetchColumn();
        if ($carModelCount > 0){
            $model_sql="SELECT DISTINCT %s% FROM cars, carmodel WHERE carmodel.id = cars.id";
            foreach (DB::getDB("mysql", 1, array("model", "modelname"))->query($model_sql) as $row){                                        
                $models .= '<option value="'.$row[model].'">'.$row[modelname].'</option>';
            }
            $return['models'] =$models;
            $return['success'] =true;
        }       
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        print "SQL Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        exit();
    }
}else{
    $return['success'] =false;
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

And most important, don't forget to serve up jquery itself. Place it in your initial PHP 
page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```